# Nested Rails Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible to embed (nest) Rails engines inside of other Rails engines?

I am working on a Rails 3.1 app that I want to split up into a couple different sections and turn each section into a Rails engines. However, I also want to be able to turn the entire app into a Rails engine.

Answer (score 1):

Possible, but not easy.
http://confreaks.com/videos/863-railsconf2012-railes-engines-patterns

Answer (score 1):

Think what benefits you get from nested engines. Nesting means coupling and if you want to improve maintainability and testability you should reduce that coupling.
I think the ideal engine should be easily able to run standalone - this is why you have `dummy` app created in `test` directory. Sure you can keep nesting or keep common stuff in main app but you will see that with growing code base it is harder to maintain tests with tightly coupled dependencies.

As a solution I would try composition instead. Put engine directories next to each other but use nested modules:

```
engines/foo_project - namespaced FooProject::*
engines/foo_project_user - namespaced FooProjectUser::* or FooProject::User::*
```

If there is something which `FooProject::User` needs from `FooProject` then ideally it shoud be extracted into another engine like `FooProject::Layout`. In another direction the main app should wire `User` stuff into `FooProject`. Add integration tests on the main app level and you get ordnung.